# About randomly selecting some rows from a table, then taking the average

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, random, cursor

Here's my problem.

I am trying to do this: there are x columns in a table in a db on sql server. I would like to randomly select n% of the rows for k times. Each time after i randomly select the rows, i take the average value of a column. Finally, I need to take the average value of the k time average.

For example,

**Original Table**

```
Gender  Height
M   182
M   183
M   178
M   165
M   183
M   158
M   192
M   171
M   173
M   165
M   174
M   166
M   188
M   176
M   174
M   162
```

**Random selection 1**

```
Gender  Height
M   182
M   183
M   178
M   165
```

-- Then calculate the avg height of the four selected

```
Gender  Avg_Height
M   177
```

**Random selection 2**

```
Gender  Height
M   158
M   176
M   174
M   171
```

-- Then calculate the avg height of the four selected

```
Gender  Avg_Height
M   170
```

Finally, compute the avg of 170 and 177, which is the final table.

```
Gender  Avg_Height
M   173.5
```

I randomly select 4 rows from the original table twice and take the average each time, then take the average of the two avg heights, finally. I know how to select random rows multiple times, but couldn't figure out how to put the final results out in a table in the DB. Thanks.

select top 4 * from original_table
order by newid()

Comment: Show the code that you have for selecting random rows, please.

Comment: select top 4 * from originaltable order by newid()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an output table, then loop through and use `INSERT INTO` to populate it:

```
CREATE TABLE output (Selection INT, Avg_Height FLOAT)
GO
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=5)
BEGIN

    WITH cte AS (SELECT TOP 4 *
                 FROM Table1
                 ORDER BY NEWID())
    INSERT INTO output
    SELECT @intFlag, AVG(Height*1.0)
    FROM cte

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/069032/1/0)

Adding `ORDER BY NEWID()` is one way to randomize the order of your results, and the above loop will run 5 times, adjust the `WHILE` portion to change the number of iterations.

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you. I just need to take one more step, ie, getting the avg of the 5-time avg. The cte is a good stuff.

Comment: So the final step for you would just be `SELECT AVG(Avg_Height) FROM output`.  If this sufficiently answers your question, please tick the checkmark by the question.  If not, please elaborate in your question what you're after.